# Optimization of SPARQL query. [ Estimated execution time exceeds the limit of 1500 (sec) ]

Tags: query-optimization, semantic-web, sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to run this query on http://dbpedia.org/sparql but I get an error that my query is too expensive. When I run the query trough http://dbpedia.org/snorql/ I get:

```
The estimated execution time 25012730 (sec) exceeds the limit of 1500 (sec) ...
```

When running the query through my python script using SPARQLWrapper I simply get an HTTP 500.

I figure I need to do something to optimize my SPARQL query. I need the data for iterating over educational institutions and importing it in to a local database, maybe I am using SPARQL wrong and should do this in a fundamentally different way.

Hope someone can help me!

## The query

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>

            SELECT DISTINCT ?uri
                ?name
                ?homepage
                ?student_count
                ?native_name
                ?city
                ?country
                ?type
                ?lat ?long
                ?image

            WHERE {
                ?uri rdf:type dbpedia-owl:EducationalInstitution .
                ?uri foaf:name ?name .
                OPTIONAL { ?uri foaf:homepage ?homepage } .
                OPTIONAL { ?uri dbpedia-owl:numberOfStudents ?student_count } .
                OPTIONAL { ?uri dbpprop:nativeName ?native_name } .
                OPTIONAL { ?uri dbpprop:city ?city } .
                OPTIONAL { ?uri dbpprop:country ?country } .
                OPTIONAL { ?uri dbpprop:type ?type } .
                OPTIONAL { ?uri geo:lat ?lat . ?uri geo:long ?long } .
                OPTIONAL { ?uri foaf:depiction ?image } .
            }
            ORDER BY ?uri
            LIMIT 20 OFFSET 10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget it. You won't be able to get that query back from dbpedia with just one SPARQL. Those optionals are very expensive.

To work it around you need to first run something like:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ?uri WHERE {
                ?uri rdf:type dbpedia-owl:EducationalInstitution .
                ?uri foaf:name ?name .
 } ORDER BY ?uri
 LIMIT 20 OFFSET 10
```

Then iterate over the resultset of this query to form single queries for each `dbpedia-owl:EducationalInstitution` such as ... (notice the filter at the end of the query):

```
        SELECT DISTINCT ?uri
            ?name
            ?homepage
            ?student_count
            ?native_name
            ?city
            ?country
            ?type
            ?lat ?long
            ?image

        WHERE {
            ?uri rdf:type dbpedia-owl:EducationalInstitution .
            ?uri foaf:name ?name .
            OPTIONAL { ?uri foaf:homepage ?homepage } .
            OPTIONAL { ?uri dbpedia-owl:numberOfStudents ?student_count } .
            OPTIONAL { ?uri dbpprop:nativeName ?native_name } .
            OPTIONAL { ?uri dbpprop:city ?city } .
            OPTIONAL { ?uri dbpprop:country ?country } .
            OPTIONAL { ?uri dbpprop:type ?type } .
            OPTIONAL { ?uri geo:lat ?lat . ?uri geo:long ?long } .
            OPTIONAL { ?uri foaf:depiction ?image } .
        FILTER (?uri = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/%C3%89cole_%C3%A9l%C3%A9mentaire_Marie-Curie>)
        }
```

Where `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/%C3%89cole_%C3%A9l%C3%A9mentaire_Marie-Curie>`  has been obtained from the first query.

... and yes it will be slow and you might not be able to run this for an online application. Advice: try to work out some sort of caching mechanism to sit between your app and the dbpedia SPARQL endpoint.

Comment: The query went from taking about 3 minutes to 42 hours to run, but it seems to work consistently now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't** try and get the entire dataset at once!  Add a `LIMIT` and a `OFFSET` clause and use those to page through the data.

With `LIMIT 50` added I get back a result for your query almost instantly, I managed to get the limit up much higher than that and still get a response so play with it.  Once you've found a page size that works for you just repeat the query with an `OFFSET` as well until you get no more results e.g.

```
SELECT * WHERE { ... } LIMIT 100
SELECT * WHERE { ... } LIMIT 100 OFFSET 100
...
```

Comment: I think the problem is not the page size but the `order by` together with the offset. As the offset grows the order by becomes more and more expensive. Not completely sure about this, but it is my guess.

Comment: I was already using limit and offset to page through the data, queries where still to expensive even when trying to get only 1 resource.

Comment: @msalvadores as I interpret the documentation it says that you have to specify ORDER BY when you have LIMIT and OFFSET in your query. "[Using LIMIT and OFFSET to select different subsets of the query solutions will not be useful unless the order is made predictable by using ORDER BY](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/#modOffset)".

Comment: @Johan Yes and no, a SPARQL processor is not required to preserve the order of the solutions unless an `ORDER BY` is used so in theory doing a query with `LIMIT 5` and then `LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5` without an `ORDER BY` the processor can legally return the same 5 results.  In practise there will often be some implicit ordering of solutions as a side effect of how the query is evaluated so using them without `ORDER BY` is generally safer and faster

Answer (score 2):

If you know the exact URI (e.g. from a previous query), then putting the URI directly in the where clause is faster (at least in my experience) than putting the URI in a FILTER.

e.g., prefer:

```
WHERE { <http:/...> ... }
```

over

```
WHERE { ?uri .... FILTER (?uri...)
```

Also I've found UNION's actually perform faster than filters designed to match multiple resources.

Just because we're doing SPARQL now doesn't mean we can forget the nightmares of SQL tuning, welcome to the wonderful world of SPARQL tuning! :)