# why is Sparql endpoint on local sever not returning the full set of entities for a given type?

Tags: c++, sparql, freebase

## Introduction

I have freebase uploaded to [Virtuoso open-source](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource). The databaset is located on the following server: http://SERVER_SPARQL:8890/sparql. I want to extract the description of all the **entities** that have the type **common.topic**.

---

## C++ class

In order to access the database I am using `curlpp` and `c++`. I am pretty sure it's not the problem of the class. I'll post it anyway.

```
#include "SparqlQuery.h"

#include <curlpp/cURLpp.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Easy.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Options.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Exception.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

SparqlQuery::SparqlQuery(const string & query, const string & url):_query(query),_url(url){}

size_t  WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

string SparqlQuery::retrieveInformations()
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    cout << _url << endl;
    string readBuffer = "";
    if(curl)
    {
        //convert string query to URL format
        char * parameters = curl_easy_escape(curl, _query.c_str(), (int)_query.size());

        //Format query according to the sparql endpoint site
        string query = "query=";
        string tothis(parameters);
        string buffer = query + tothis;

        curl_free(parameters);

        //Launch query and retrieve informations in form of an xml structure
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, _url.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, buffer.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return readBuffer;
}
```

---

## Number of entities

When I use the following query, it returns **43453748** entities that are of the type **common.topic**. Which is fine

```
void loadData()
{
  cout <<"loading data" << endl;
  string serverURL = "http://SERVER_SPARQL:8890/sparql";
  string query = "select count(*) where {?head <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://rdf.basekb.com/ns/common.topic>.}";

  SparqlQuery sparql(query, severURL);
  string result = sparql.retrieveInformations();
  cout << result << endl;
}
```

---

## Problem

When I use the following query it doesn't output more than 10,000 entities. Even If I try the query from a browser it's not returning the full set of entities. Do you have any idea on why it doesn't return the full results? It's as if there is a limit for the results.

```
void Freebase::loadData()
{
  cout <<"loading data" << endl;
  string serverURL = "http://SERVER_SPARQL:8890/sparql";
  string query = "select ?head, ?description where { ?head <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://rdf.basekb.com/ns/common.topic>.?head <http://rdf.basekb.com/ns/common.topic.description>  ?description.}";

  SparqlQuery sparql(query, serverURL);
  string result = sparql.retrieveInformations();
  cout << result << endl;
}
```

---

## Modifications

I tried to modify the class by adding should-sponge option but now the problem is the following:

> Virtuoso 22023 Error SR078: The result set is too long, must limit
>   result for at most 2097151 rows (DAMN IT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!)

```
using namespace std;

SparqlQuery::SparqlQuery(const string & query, const string & url):_query(query),_url(url){}

size_t  WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

string SparqlQuery::retrieveInformations()
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    cout << _url << endl;
    string readBuffer = "";
    if(curl)
    {
        //convert string query to URL format
        char * parameters = curl_easy_escape(curl, _query.c_str(), (int)_query.size());
    string val = "grab-all-seealso";
    char * sponge_parameters = curl_easy_escape(curl, val.c_str(), (int)val.size());

        //Format query according to the sparql endpoint site
    string should_sponge= "should-sponge=";
    string last(sponge_parameters);
    string buffer1 = should_sponge + last;

        string query = "query=";
        string tothis(parameters);
        string buffer = query + tothis +"&"+ buffer1;
        cout << buffer << endl;

        curl_free(parameters);
    curl_free(sponge_parameters);

        //Launch query and retrieve informations in form of an xml structure
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, _url.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, buffer.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return readBuffer;
}
```

---

## Update

As suggested I actually used `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280670/optimization-of-sparql-query-estimated-execution-time-exceeds-the-limit-of-15) It's not necessary to use `ORDER BY`. Which in fact suits me better. It's much faster and i am not getting a time limit exception.

```
for(int offset = 1000; ;offset += 1000 )
  {
    string query = "PREFIX basekb:<http://rdf.basekb.com/ns/> PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> select distinct ?head ?label where { ?head rdf:type basekb:common.topic. ?head rdfs:label ?label}LIMIT 1000 OFFSET " + std::to_string(offset) ;
    SparqlQuery sparql(query, _serverURL);
    string result = sparql.retrieveInformations();
    cout << result << endl;
  }
```

I just have one more question please. How will I know if I crossed the offest limit? hope that I wont be getting duplicate results.

---

Comment: `should-sponge` and `grab-all-seealso` is most likely not what you want

Comment: Based on the properties in your example, it appears that you're actually using BaseKB, not Freebase.  While it applies pre-processing & cleaning which is generally useful, you may want to review the transformations which applied, so that you understand how it differs from the original Freebase data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To a first approximation, all entities with a `common.topic.description` property will be of type `common.topic`, so a simpler way to do this for many applications would be to just use `grep` on the source RDF file to look for all the lines with `common.topic.description` triples.

This will give you an answer in minutes instead of hours.

If you want to stick with SPARQL, try adding `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses to your query and iterating to get all the results (as mentioned by Joshua Taylor, but buried in a comment).

Comment: true, and goes along the lines of [one of my blog posts](https://joernhees.de/blog/2015/01/28/dbpedia-2014-stats-top-subjects-predicates-and-objects/)... but only really viable for "easy" queries...

Comment: @Tom Morris I give up i Am using the following command `riot a-m-*.nt | \grep '<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>`

I remember that you told me about it once. I'll be reading all the files **a-m-*.nt** that contains the topics. they go from **a-m-00000.nt** to **a-m-00028.nt**

Comment: it's much much faster

Answer (score 1):

You are restricting your sparql query with :

```
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Even without the LIMIT 10  it's still not giving me the full set of results. I don't get it

Comment: @HaniGoc forty-three-million results is a lot to return.  I don't expect that most SPARQL endpoints will allow you to get them all at once.  You'll need to use OFFSET/LIMIT/ORDER BY.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor actually sadly even OFFSET + LIMIT + ORDER BY pagination doesn't seem to get you past certain limits. I've tried on a local endpoint but never succeeded to get more than ~1.5 M results with this kind of paging. One of the Virtuoso developers told our group to use the command line / jdbc drivers if we want to do those kind of queries.

Answer (score 1):

When using SPARQL via HTTP Virtuoso seems to impose a lot of restrictions on your queries and how the result sets are constructed. One that i've frequently heard but can't really understand is that the maximum result set size (despite `virtuoso.ini` settings) seems to be 1M rows.

There are a couple of sadly less "open" ways to run SPARQL queries on a Virtuoso endpoint that don't fall under these restrictions.

What i'd probably try first if you don't need to do this programmatically over and over again and if you control the server: try to run the query in the `isql`/`isql-vt` command line interface. You can just run sparql queries from there like this:

```
sparql select * {?s ?p ?o} limit 10;
```

There also seems to be a `CSV` variable that you can set to get "CSV" like output, but be aware that the [encoding is weird](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/421).

Other options are the ODBC/JDBC connectors e.g., like the one the [DWSLab](https://github.com/dwslab/dwslib/blob/master/src/main/java/de/dwslab/dwslib/virtuoso/Query.java) is using.